# FirstorDefault() causes lazy loading or eager loading for linq to sql

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

What is default behavior of FirstOrDefault() when used with Linq to SQL?

For e.g

```
  int value =   (from p in context.tableX         
                select p.Id).FirstOrDefault()      // Value will initialized here or

   if(value > 0)                      // query will be executed here????
   {
    //do something
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: Only Entities and `IEnumerable` are lazyloaded.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is default behavior of FirstOrDefault() when used with Linq to SQL?

It eagerly computes the result of the query. The easiest way to reckon about this is to realize that the return type is `int`, not `IEnumerable<int>` which *can* be deferred until `GetEnumerator` is called, but `int` has no such mechanism.

The phrasing of your question suggests that you're also asking if there is a way to change this behavior. There is, but not directly through `FirstOrDefault` or any mechanisms within LINQ. But you can defer using [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx). No compiler handy, so forgive me if this doesn't compile but it should get you very close.

```
Lazy<int> value = new Lazy<int>(
    () => {
        var query =
            from p in context.tableX
            select p.Id;
        var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
        return result;
    }
);

if(value.Value > 0) { // execution will be deferred until here
    //
}
```

Comment: @Iti Tyagi - Sounds like you are asking whether FirstOrDefault() will initiate a call to GetEnumerator. Would query.FirstOrDefault() result in lazy loading or eager loading (i.e. will it call GetEnumerator or not)? I believe something like query.ToList() would force an eager load - would FirstOrDefault() do the same?

Answer (score 12):

All standard Linq operators, which return **single, non-enumerable result**, are executed immediately at the point where query is *declared*. So, `FirstOrDefault`, `Count`, `Sum` and other operators which return single value are executed immediately.

Here is nice MSDN article [Classification of Standard Query Operators by Manner of Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Eager loading!

If you think about it, it just returns a plain `int` - an `int` can't possibly represent "a way to go and get an `int`". (That's what `Lazy<int>` is for...)

Answer (score 2):

It becomes Eager loading when you use extension methods on the enumerable result.If you don't use those extension methods it will be Lazy loading and you can't actually fetch the values until you enumerate through the linq result